# How does bashrc function differently from bash_profile?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, gpg

I have been losing my mind due to IntelliJ not wanting to commit my code. I had put `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` into my `.bash_profile` instead of my `.bashrc`; echoing `$GPG_TTY` responded with the proper path, but I still kept getting the `gpg: failed to sign the data` error.

From what I gather, `.bash_profile` is read and executed when Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, while `.bashrc` is executed for an interactive non-login shell; `$PATH` variables should thus go into the `.bash_profile`...? Or, at least, so I thought. I'd like to know what the functional difference is between the two: why didn't it work from my profile but it does from the rc?

Comment: Is IntelliJ starting a login shell?

Comment: Are you on macOS?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, I am on Linux. I guess what White Owl said in his answer cleared things up. I didn't know that it was "pointless" to have a `.bash_profile` if you run a desktop system which has a GUI, and instead just dump things into the `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to a problem: put the `export var` into `.bashrc`, and call the `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`.

Yes, the difference is login vs non-login. The `bash` would be in login mode, when you login to `bash`, for example through `ssh` or on a non-gui machine. But once you logged in, all new instances of bash would be started in non-login mode.

If you having a GUI desktop, you will login into WM and not into the `bash`. So you would never have `bash` in a login mode (unless you specifically call it with a `--login` option). So it is kind of pointless to even have `.bash_profile` on a workstation with GUI.
But you still can have it, in case you will login to that machine-user through `ssh`, or your WM break and you need to start a recovery procedures.

And of course, the official documentation is a must read:
https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: Didn't know about the GUI stuff. Thanks for clearing that up. I'll just ignore the `.bash_profile`, then.